# How do I make sample photos for cameras/lenses?

Tags: composition, tests, comparison

If I want to compare different cameras or lenses, what properties should the photos that I use have? And what should I do in order to get the most information?

I can think of the following, but probably it's just a subset:

- Good lighting (how do I define that?)
- Proper exposition and manual settings;
- Same aperture and field of view (the focal length might differ) - is there a "scientific way to do this?";
- Scene with good amount of details, colors and contrasts;
- Use of a tripod (?)

Also, what can I do if I want typical lens flaws (distortion, chromatic aberration) to pop out?

Answer (score 2):

When I do such photos I alway use:

- a tripod to make sure the photo shows the same especially in the corners
- M-Mode with fix ISO-Settings to make sure exposure is same (be careful with fluctuating available light)

Often but not alway I use flash and "kill" the available light to avoid light fluctuations.

To analyses distortions I often use checkered paper or other objects with straight lines.

> Scene with good amount of details, colors and contrasts

Yes, a good idea. Use test constructions like [this](http://www.heise.de/ct/testbilder/Testkiste_gesamt_400.jpg) or [this](http://www.heise.de/foto/imgs/13/2/2/5/2/9/5/0db219d7a648d38c.jpg).